# What's the equivalent String.prototype? ／ String.prototype === String; //false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I tried below.

It was operating as expected.

```
   String.constructor === Function; //true
   String.prototype.constructor===String; //true
```

---

It did not work as expected.

```
String.prototype === String; //false
```

---

I want know ★★.

What's the equivalent String.prototype?

```
String.prototype === ★★; //true
```

---

**Additional questions**

it is a unique object
and It is a 「String.prototype === String.prototype;」 is

it the same meaning as the following?

```
String.prototype===String.prototype.constructor.prototype; //true
```

Comment: `String.prototype` is an object that contains all the String methods.  It's not clear what you're really asking.   `typeof String.prototype  === "object"`

Comment: The only thing that would satisfy your identity test is `String.prototype === String.prototype` because it is a unique object.

Answer (score 1):

Every function (`String` is a function) has its own "unique" `prototype` object. So there is no equivalent.